# Replace a column values with another reference

Tags: excel, replace

I have a column with separated values,I need to replace these values base on a reference, here is the example of my request (colored by green)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In B1 and copied down to suit:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"1","One"),"2","Two"),"3","Three"),"4","Four"),"5","Five"),"6","Six"),"7","Seven"),"8","Eight"),"9","Nine")
```

(Thanks to [dalakomala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7570245/dalakomala) for doing most of the typing.)